# How can I concatenate

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I concatenate two XML element attributes?

I have the following input XML:

```
<Fields header="EXAMPLE" delim=" " xmlns:m="http://myserver">
  <Field prefix="cs1" name="example" label="Test" />
  <Field prefix="cs2" name="**toConcatenate**" label="Test 2" />
</Fields
```

and am hoping that I can achieve (via an XSL transform ideally) the following output:

```
<Fields header="EXAMPLE" delim=" " xmlns:m="http://myserver">
  <Field prefix="cs3" name="exampletoConcatenate"/>
</Fields
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Are you always going to have only 2 elements that you need to concatenate together or can it be multiple elements? Which version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: @Sebastien I've been testing options with both XSLT 1 and 2 without a lot of luck - ideally, owing to the application that will be parsing the content, 1 would be preferable since it's pretty old and may not have a solid XSLT 2 implementation!

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I'm able to see how to do a merge of two *values* using XSLT, but can't see anyone talking about merging two attributes - i.e. I know I can do: ```<xsl:value of select=concat(ExampleField1,ExampleField2)"/>``` but I can't see a reference for setting the value of an attribute? I'll be honest, XSLT isn't my strongest skillset (and would gladly take some documentation starting points as a "starter for 10!"

Comment: *"I can't see a reference for setting the value of an attribute?"* Here's one: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#creating-attributes. Here's another: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it simply like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:m="http://myserver"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Fields">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <Field prefix="cs3" name="{concat(Field[1]/@name,Field[2]/@name)}"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGm

This assumes you only have 2 elements you want to concatenate.
In XSLT 1 if you have N number of elements you would need to add a loop to concatenate all attributes. In XSLT 2 you could simply do Field/@name and it will give you the concatenation of all attributes.